# HTML5 hyper links between two pages

Tags: html

I'm studying HTML5 and i need to create a hyperlink from on page to an id location on the second one.

Both HTML files are in the same folder.

What I tried so far is here:

```
<a href="#Web-Overwiev/index.html/browser.html">World Wide Web overview</a>
<a href="#Web-Overwiev/index.html">World wide web overview</a>
```

None of these worked for me so far.

I tried looking for answers online and didn't find anything related.

I could try to find the needed code by looking in to an existing code of a page with the same function that I'm looking for, but I'm not familiar with a page like that while looking for a page on the web is impractical.

Comment: It will be hard to tell not knowing how those files are called but I guess the `href` should actually be `browser.html#Web-Overview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to link to a specific id location on a page, you need to put it after the URL like so:

```html
<a href="index.html#Web-Overview">World Wide Web overview</a>
```

The `#` part indicates to the browser that this is an id of an anchor on the `index.html` page. This anchor would look like this:

```html
<a href="" id="Web-Overview">Some Text</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: YES! THANK YOU!!